# Batch indexing to solr

Tags: java, solr

I have a java class that sends http post requests to a solr instance to index json files. it is implemented in a multithreaded manner. However, I have realized that sending so many http requests (close to 20,000) is causing the network to be a bottle neck. I read online that I can do batch indexing, but I can't find any clear examples. Is there any advice to batch index solr?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sending generic JSON files or Solr's document format JSON? The latest supports sending multiple documents at once.

Comment: I'm sending generic json.

Answer (score 0):

For generic JSON, you must have a configuration somewhere in solrconfig.xml that defines how it is treated.

One of the parameters is [split](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-TransformingandIndexingCustomJSON). You might be able to use it to combine your JSON documents into a one bigger one that Solr would split and process separately. Notice that the specific format may be a little different for different Solr versions. Get the correct version of the downloadable reference guide PDF, if something is not working.

Or, if you can generate it, use [JSON format Solr understands directly](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-JSONFormattedIndexUpdates) and which has full support for multiple documents.